# How do I make sure sudo is setuid in repackaged squashfs?

Tags: sudo, setuid, yocto, squashfs

I'm trying to manipulate a squashfs file, containing a yocto build and an application payload, but everytime I do so, `sudo` fails to execute afterwards. root user is disabled, so I have no real alternative.

My approach is to just unpack the filesystem and then repackage the unpacked files. In that process the owner is set to my local user (which is fine -- I can fix that) and, it seems, setuid is removed from sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `unsquashfs` to unpack the files, you will get a set of files owned by you and with no setuid bits. But you can manually put back the setuid bit on any files you want (with `chmod u+s`); of course they will be setuid to your id. But when you repackage the files using `mksquashfs` add the option `-all-root` and all the files in the filesystem will be owned by root, not you, and any setuid bit will be preserved.